# Publish Win32 Project on Website

Tags: c++, asp.net, web-services, web, visual-studio-2013

I programmed a GUI on Visual Studio C++ using Win API. Now, I would like to embed/publish the GUI on a webpage so that users who visit the webpage could use it.

Is it possible? Is there a way to do it? When I compile the codes on the Visual Studio C++, is there a specific file that will allow me to embed this program on a webpage?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A Windows form cannot be displayed on a web page, you're going to have to create a web form.

An if you really want to display something like windows form on the web page,
I think you may interested in [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/spano/archive/2007/09/19/hosting-a-windows-form-control-in-a-web-page.aspx) and [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20210619191631/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052604-1.aspx)

However, personally, I would suggest you to just create a pure web form instead.